# Use of undeclared identifier in my CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to create my own cocoapod. Everything was OK until I've tried use my pod in a example project.

Cocoapods downloaded my project and I am able to import pod. But I can't use any file from this pod. Using any fail leads to `Use of undeclared identifier` error. But all files are already in the project.

[image]

Deleting of derived data and cleaning project don't help me.

What could be wrong?

P.S. This is the link to my project if needed. https://github.com/EugeneTrapeznikov/ETCollapsableTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making ETCollapsableTableItem public:

```
public class ETCollapsableTableItem
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: @greentor how can we make this in objective c?